# PHP array with multiple delimiters

Tags: php, arrays, explode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSON Parsing with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889738/json-parsing-with-php)

I'm hoping for a little assistance on this. I trying to take what's in my `$data` variable:

```
[{"Product":"Internal",
  "Rank":"1",
  "Number":"1234"},
 {"Product":"External",
 "Rank":"1",
 "Number":"5678"}]
```

and turn it into an associative array that is something like this:

```
Product[0] => Internal,
Rank[0] => 1,
Number[0] => 1234,
Product[1] => External,
Rank[1]  => 1,
Number[1] => 5678
```

The closest I've been able to get is using the following code:

```
$del='/[{: ,}]/';
$data = preg_split($del,$data);
print_r($data);
```

Which gives me something like this:

> Array ( [0] => [ [1] => "Product" [2] => "1 [3] => 1" [4] => "Rank"
>   [5] => "1"

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Your input data is in JSON. There is a function that does what you want, `json_decode`: check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that `$data` is in JSON format, you could just do this:

```
$data = json_decode($data);
```

Then you want to iterate through the array of objects and transmogrify them:

```
$output = array();
foreach($data as $index=>$object) {
    foreach($object as $name=>$value) {
        $output[$name][$index] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use `json_decode($data,TRUE)`, this will make your life easier, giving you nice array to transform in what you want.